# Build failed via terminal, cordova android

Tags: android, cordova

I'm receiving an error in my terminal when attempting to `cordova build android` on my mac to finish building my cordova project. It's telling me that it could not find version for google play services as seen below. Does anyone know what is a potential fix?

➜  AppTest  cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/chrono/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
  >   Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/maven-metadata.xml
  >        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-analytics/
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

### My installed plugins

- cordova-plugin-dialogs
- cordova-plugin-google-app-conversion-tracker
- cordova-plugin-googleplayservices
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
- cordova-plugin-network-information
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen
- cordova-plugin-statusbar
- cordova-plugin-whitelist
- cordova-sqlite-storage
- de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer
- de.appplant.cordova.plugin.printer

Answer (score 0):

Your build.gradle file is messed up. Do the following:

```
cordova platform rm android
```

and when finished, throw a:

```
cordova platform add android
```